# Using XSL to replace XML element text

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to replace 6.4.2 with 6.3.5 using XSL.  I am very new to XSL and could use some help.  Thank you in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transmission>
    <TransmissionHeader>
        <Version>6.4.2</Version>
```

Comment: You could do it programmatically, can't you?

Comment: Unless it can be done in the stylesheet I'm unaware how to.  I personally only use SQL & PL/SQL and have limited experience with XSL.  This is a one off case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to replace the content of *Version* element,
not each occurrence of this text in source XML.
I also assume, that your XML contains **only one** such element
and we are not interested in its source content.

The easiest way to do it is to write a template matching just this element.
And as far as its content is concerned, the easiest way to write
it is to generate a **literal element** with new (changed) content.

To copy all remaining content "as is", you need the *identity template*.

So the whole script cal look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Version">
    <Version>6.3.5</Version>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will attempt this.  Do you know what I did in the below code that would have not worked?

Comment: <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="Version/text()[.='6.4.2']">6.3.5</xsl:template>

Comment: If your script is **all** what you wrote above, then the error is that
the root tag of *XSLT* script should be either *stylesheet*
or *transform*.
It is also a good habit to put `<xsl:output indent="yes" />`
at the beginning of the script.
I placed your code in *transform* tag and I see that is also works.
For an example see http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ3m
If you are sure about the source content of *Value* tag and your task
is just to replace its content (as I assumed), you can delete the
predicate `[...]` from your code.

Comment: Thank you, Valdi_Bo!  You're of great assistance and I've learned something new today!  Have a good day.  Hopefully, as I become more accustomed to Stack Overflow and set up my profile more I will be able to return the favor one day.